# How can I find number of components in a graph if no.edges > no.vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

Here I counted 8 vertices and 15 edges. Every component must be tree with n vertices, and n-1 edges right? So then, how can I calculate the number of components?

Comment: This is a connected graph, so there is only one component.

Comment: @David: Are you *defining* "component" to be a tree containing all the graph's vertices (as opposed to the usage "connected component")? Such a thing is typically called a ["spanning tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).